# How to get the original points the cluster contained using ELKI's DBSCAN?

Tags: elki

I have 2 questions for the following code:

1. How to get the 'points' in each cluster in the result?
2. How could the result contains 3 clusters with one that has size is 0?

   ```
   import de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.model.Model;
   import de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.StaticArrayDatabase;
   import de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection;
   import de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.DatabaseConnection;
   import de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.distance.distancefunction.geo.LatLngDistanceFunction;
   import de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.math.geodesy.WGS84SpheroidEarthModel;
   import java.util.List;
   import de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.clustering.DBSCAN;
   import de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.Cluster;
   import de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.Clustering;
   import de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.DoubleVector;

   /**
    *
    * @author Paul Z. Wu Jan 14, 2018
    */
   public class DBScan {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       final double[][] data = new double[][]{{48.774332, -78.532054}, {40.774032, -73.531154},
       {40.774232, -73.531084}, {48.774332, -78.531054}};
       DatabaseConnection dbc = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(data);
       DBSCAN<DoubleVector> scan = new DBSCAN<>(new LatLngDistanceFunction(WGS84SpheroidEarthModel.STATIC), 2000, 1);
       StaticArrayDatabase db = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc, null);
       db.initialize();
       Clustering<Model> c = scan.run(db);


       System.out.println(c.getAllClusters().isEmpty());
       List<Cluster<Model>> list = c.getAllClusters();
       for (Cluster<Model> cl : list) {
           System.out.println("size=" + cl.size());
           System.out.println("...." + cl.getIDs() + "..." + cl.getModel() + "  ");
           //How to get the original 'points' in this cluster? One of them should
           //contain {40.774032, -73.531154},{40.774232, -73.531084}
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Use `db.getRelation`. Empty noise? Noise is not a cluster, use `getNoise` or so to see which "cluster" has the unclustered points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [tutorial.javaapi.PassingDataToELKI line 73](https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/e8f3c6fd/addons/tutorial/src/main/java/tutorial/javaapi/PassingDataToELKI.java#L73)

```
Relation<NumberVector> rel = db.getRelation(TypeUtil.NUMBER_VECTOR_FIELD);
```

and See [tutorial.javaapi.PassingDataToELKI lines 102-104](https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/e8f3c6fd/addons/tutorial/src/main/java/tutorial/javaapi/PassingDataToELKI.java#L102-104)

```
for(DBIDIter it = clu.getIDs().iter(); it.valid(); it.advance()) {
    // To get the vector use:
    NumberVector v = rel.get(it);
}
```

ELKI uses a "**tidy data**" architecture. Most algorithms expect a database relation (think: column, or table) of vectors. Not unlike column stores, actually, but there is nothing to be gainen on the side of compression on continuous dense data. Often with a fixed dimensionality (=a vector field). For geodata, you could even specify this to have exactly 2 dimensions.

Labels would be stored in a second relation/table/column.

Also see the GeoIndexing example to scale DBSCAN to larger data sets. I have used OPTICS on 23 million geo coordinates, but it takes a while to run, obviously (not days, though). I recommend enabling progress logging for large data sets, which even tries to estimate the remaining time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Could you also give me the tip on how to use the database relation that has 2 fields lat, lng and other attributes, but I only use the first 2 fields for clustering, the rest is informational. I could define 2 'separate' arrays for this or some kind of hash table...all these  cost memory.

Comment: There is a geo distance function where you can specify the columns to use. Then you don't need to split the vectors. Or you build multiple relations. See the source code of `ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection`.